# loading data from external stage - passing stage name to a parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ksh

I'm using snowsql in a ksh script which loading data from a named external stage to snowflake table. My ksh

```
    snowsql -c $CONNECT -w $WAREHOUSE -s $SCHEMA -d $DATABASE \
            --filename "my_sql_file" \
            -D stage_parameter=${external_stage_name}
```

and "my_sql_file" is

```
Copy into "table"
from (select $1 as column1, $2 as column2 from &stage_parameter)
```

This gave an error - seems like the stage parameter couldnt pass to sql file. Does anyone know why?
Thanks.

Comment: you're not showing where external_stage_name is defined?

Comment: Not sure whether this works in a copy into statement, but have you tried wrapping the table name in an IDENTIFER() function?

Comment: Which error message ?
What is the `external_stage_name` content ?
Does contains spaces ?